# How can windows users who only log in through a browser change their password?

Tags: security, reporting-services, passwords, windows-server

I am helping to run a reporting services installation that is protected and gains its permission structure with Windows usernames and passwords. Our password policy dictates that passwords change once a month. Three of the five users of this installation only log in to the report manager site with their windows logins using their browsers.

At present every month I have to remote desktop into the box and change the passwords with my administrator's account and then tell the users what their new passwords are myself. They inevitably end up writing the new passwords down and this is far from the ideal scenario.

Microsoft claim that the "Change Password" dialog should be able to change the Windows login for any windows box which can be reached. The problem I have is that these boxes can only be reached by remote desktop or via the internet. I have tried entering the report server URL as a domain and the external IP of the serving box as a domain but the password dialog does not recognise these as valid domains.

Is there any way that I can provide users with a method for changing their password via their local windows boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, for the sake of closure I'm going to add this answer and mark it as the correct answer as the question appears to be dead. If anyone has a further suggestion I believe I can re mark the correct answer at a later date. For now... case closed without resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the website is hosted on the server the users log into, you could run a `NET USER {Usernamehere} {Password}` to replace the password.

You could probably do it over the network but this would get more complicated.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for something they could do themselves. If I have to do it I might as well use the current approach.

Comment: No, I mean, I assume they are using a web frontend cause they are accessing it through the browser, program the frontend to run that query once the user is authenticated with the correct variables.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think that once the policy term has expired the old password is automatically abandoned. If you log in through TS or similar it warns you that the password will expire, but through the web it doesn't. The complaint I got from a user was that it didn't even ask for a password just skipped straight to telling them they were not authorised to view the page.

Comment: Well that's a problem with the web frontend, I can't exactly see what's going on.

Comment: This is a Reporting Services installation. Reporting Services out of the box uses Windows Integrated Authentication, so when you visit the site a pop up box requests your windows password. I want a simple way for remote users to change that password remotely.